# KO External Template Engine/HotTowel Template/Infuser Loading

Tags: knockout.js, template-engine, hottowel

I'm trying to use KO external template engine with the Hot Towel template by John Papa.
The template is not loading, well, it keeps on saying "Loading....".
I looked at the Chrome debugger and it shows that the template was retrieved successfully.
I can see the code rendered in the DOM

```
<div class="infuser-loading">Loading...</div>
```

Here's what I've done.
1) Download latest KO External Template engine using Nuget

2) Added to BundleConfig:
TrafficCop.js, infuser.js, koExternalTemplateEngine.js

3) Added to config.js to initialise infuser and called from shell.js.

```
var configureExternalTemplates = function () {
    infuser.defaults.templatePrefix = "_";
    infuser.defaults.templateSuffix = ".tmpl.html";
    infuser.defaults.templateUrl = "./App/tmpl";
    infuser.defaults.ajax
};
```

4) In the view, I tried to call:

```
<div class="view-list" data-bind="template: { name: 'Listbox', foreach: object }">
</div>
```

As mentioned I can see in the trace that the template file is loaded properly with status 200. /App/tmpl/_listbox.tmpl.html

**What I noticed is that after refreshing a few times, eventually the template shows.**

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The KO external template library loads templates as needed. Durandal (part of Hot Towel) does this for you with its modules and require.js. So you should not need the KO external template engine at all.

Comment: Hi John, thanks for the reply. Are you suggesting to use Durandal compose tag instead or the knockout template functionality?

Comment: so in another words <!-- ko compose..... --> instead of the <div data-bind="template: { name: 'person-template', data: seller }"></div>??

Comment: Yes, exactly. The compose binding will let you bind to a module (in your case a template/view with a corresponding viewmodel).

Comment: But how could we handle cases where the template binding is used implicitly, like RNiemeyers sortable binding?

Comment: I'm having this issue only for Firefox. Other browsers its working fine. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with this engine which described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17373567/knockout-template-stays-in-loading-in-some-cases).

I've just changed it to Durandal and everything is OK now.

Durandal has much cleaner approaches for module loading and view composition ([A replied question about their comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18826928/is-durandas-compose-a-good-replacement-over-knockout-templates)).