# Knockout template stays in loading in some cases

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, knockout-templating

I used a template in my application like:

```
<section class="view-list" data-bind="template: { name: viewTemplate, foreach: locaFacts }">
```

but in some cases, mostly on the first load the output html is lots of `Loading...` instead of real templates.

It seems that knockout shows `Loading...` until the view model gets ready. As I cached the results, the second call will show the templates correctly.

Why the first call to template shows `Loading...` instead of template itself?

**EDIT:**

I use knockout external templates and infuser.

Comment: There no functionality built in to Knockout which would show these "Loading..." messages. So it is shown by your own code or you are using some other plugin which does this....

Comment: @nemesv Yep, I used ko external template and infuser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my template engine and used Durandal's `compose` feature.
Now everything is OK.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to correct this by setting ajax option async to false by modifying the template binding like so:

```
<div class="pagination" data-bind="template: { name: 'pager', data: pager, ajax: { async: false } }">
```

Comment: It seems a good solution. Thanks for letting me know about this feature. But I'm not able to test it now as I migrated to Durandal!